# Flutter Secure Storage error Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to make a Flutter app that contains a login screen and then home screen (only two screens for now). I am using Flutter Secure Storage and Http libraries too.

Whenever the app launches, I want the app to check if two props, accessKey and accessId, are stored in the Secure storage. If accessId is not found, it is auto-generated and assigned with the Uuid library. Whereas the accessKey is not generated locally and is provided by an API.

App navigates to:
1). **HomeScreen, if accessKey is stored in Secure Storage and authentication succeeds.**
2). **SignInScreen, if accessKey is not found or authentication fails.**

My problem is, Secure Storage keeps throwing error "***Null check operator used on a null value***", everytime I perform a read operation. I have initialized the storage variable, yet this problem keeps happening.

Here is my Secure Storage class code:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class FAS {
  static FlutterSecureStorage? _storage;

  static void init() {
    _storage = const FlutterSecureStorage(
      aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true),
    );
  }

  static Future<String?> read(String key) async {
    return _storage!.read(key: key);
  }

  static Future<Map<String, String>> readAll() async {
    return _storage!.readAll();
  }

  static Future<void> write(String key, String value) async {
    await _storage!.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  static Future<void> delete(String key) async {
    await _storage!.delete(key: key);
  }

  static Future<void> deleteAll() async {
    await _storage!.deleteAll();
  }
}
```

Before, the section of that code was this:

```
static const FlutterSecureStorage _storage = FlutterSecureStorage(aOptions: AndroidOptions(encryptedSharedPreferences: true));
```

There was no init method.

Yet I keep getting the same error.

Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unified_bot_app/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import './models/fas.dart';
import './pages/sign_in_page.dart';
import './request_methods.dart';

Future<void> tryAssignAccessId() async {
  String? accessId = await FAS.read("ACCESS_ID");
  if (accessId == null) {
    await FAS.write("ACCESS_ID", (const Uuid()).v4());
  }
}

void main() {
  FAS.init();
  tryAssignAccessId(); // <- Error  

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        builder: (ctx, a) {
          if (a.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (a.data!) return HomePage();
            return const SignInPage();
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
        future: () async {
          try {
            String? accessKey = await FAS.read("ACCESS_KEY");
            if (accessKey == null) {
              return false;
            }

            return await HTTP.authenticate(accessKey);
          } catch (e) {
            return false;
          }
        }(),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "Josefin Sans"),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here is the output I get when I restart the app:

> Restarted application in 531ms. E/flutter (20760):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null
> check operator used on a null value E/flutter (20760): #0
> MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:121 E/flutter
> (20760): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:146 E/flutter
> (20760): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:329 E/flutter
> (20760): #3      MethodChannelFlutterSecureStorage.read
> package:flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel_flutter_secure_storage.dart:49
> E/flutter (20760): #4      FlutterSecureStorage.read
> package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart:91
> E/flutter (20760): #5      FAS.read
> package:unified_bot_app/models/fas.dart:13 E/flutter (20760): #6
> tryAssignAccessId package:unified_bot_app/main.dart:10 E/flutter
> (20760): #7      main package:unified_bot_app/main.dart:18 E/flutter
> (20760): #8      _runMainZoned..
> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25) E/flutter (20760): #9      _rootRun
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13) E/flutter (20760): #10
> _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19) E/flutter (20760): #11     _runZoned   (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10) E/flutter (20760): #12     runZonedGuarded   (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12) E/flutter (20760): #13
> _runMainZoned. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:141:5) E/flutter (20760): #14       _delayEntrypointInvocation.
> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19) E/flutter (20760): #15
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)   E/flutter (20760):
> D/EGL_emulation(20760): app_time_stats: avg=14143.50ms min=14143.50ms
> max=14143.50ms count=1

However, the error disappears when I place first two lines in the end (after runApp(..)):

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        builder: (ctx, a) {
          if (a.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (a.data!) return HomePage();
            return const SignInPage();
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
        future: () async {
          try {
            String? accessKey = await FAS.read("ACCESS_KEY"); // <- Error re-appears here  
            if (accessKey == null) {
              return false;
            }

            return await HTTP.authenticate(accessKey);
          } catch (e) {
            return false;
          }
        }(),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "Josefin Sans"),
    ),
  );

  FAS.init();
  tryAssignAccessId();
}
```

But doing that, the error then re-appears on the marked line.

I am confused. What's happening?
Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**:
I tried calling the init() method before I call the second read() method, yet the same error is thrown.

Updated section:

```
future: () async {
          try {
            FAS.init();
            String? accessKey = await FAS.read("ACCESS_KEY");
            if (accessKey == null) {
              return false;
            }

            return await HTTP.authenticate(accessKey);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            return false;
          }
        }(),
```

Console output:

> Restarted application in 510ms. I/flutter (20760): Null check operator
> used on a null value D/EGL_emulation(20760): app_time_stats:
> avg=1899.03ms min=1899.03ms max=1899.03ms count=1

Comment: what is `FAS.init();`? is it `async`?

Comment: And try to use empty string instead of null, with something like this: `String accessKey = await FAS.read("ACCESS_KEY")??"";`

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך No FAS.init() is not async

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I tried that as well but even if ACCESS_KEY is present in the Secure Storage, it still returns the blank string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

to the main() method before runApp().

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a new Blank page containing all the methods.

Blank page file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../models/fas.dart';
import '../request_methods.dart';
import './home_page.dart';
import './sign_in_page.dart';

class BlankPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> _tryAssignAccessId() async {
    String? accessId = await FAS.read("ACCESS_ID");
    if (accessId == null) {
      await FAS.write("ACCESS_ID", (const Uuid()).v4());
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _checkAuth() async {
    try {
      String? accessKey = await FAS.read("ACCESS_KEY");
      if (accessKey == null) {
        return false;
      }

      return await HTTP.authenticate(accessKey);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FAS.init();
    _tryAssignAccessId();
    _checkAuth().then((result) {
      if (result) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => HomePage()));
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const SignInPage()));
      }
    });

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Updated main.dart (for ref.):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './pages/blank.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: BlankPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "Josefin Sans"),
    ),
  );
}
```